# While loop doesn't work inside my for loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops, validation, if-statement, while-loop

```
    mi_path = "F:\\releases\\"
    validate = False
    for dirs, paths, files in os.walk(mi_path): 
        while not validate:
            if str(release_buscar) in str(dirs):
                print("Release encontrada", dirs)
                break
            else:
                print("Release no encontrada")
                release_buscar =  input("Introduce el nombre otra vez:")
                validate = False
    print("Final del bucle")
```

I want to list all dirs from a route how I am doing and then find a string in that route. I need to do if string in dirs then make something if that string isn't in, then ask again for a valid string

I get the dirs with `os.walk` function and it return a string with dirs from the route. Then I want to find a string in a string(dirs).

The problem if what never find the folder, always jump to the `else:`.

Comment: I don't want that exactly. I want list of all dirs from a rute how i am doing and then find a string in that rutes. i need do if string in dirs then make something if that string dont not in then ask again for a valid string. –

Answer (score 1):

for that you can use `os.path.exists("my_dir")` and your code gonna be something like

```
import os

def get_existing_dir():
    my_dir = input("Please enter a directory name : ")
    while True:
        if os.path.exists(my_dir):
            return my_dir
        my_dir = input("Please enter an existing directory name : ")
```

Comment: I don't want that exactly. I want list of all dirs from a rute how i am doing and then find a string in that rutes. i need do if string in dirs then make something if that string dont not in then ask again for a valid string.